# lein uberjar doesn't pack the jar file under resource into the final jar

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I defined  :resource-paths  in profile.clj to include some special jar (vertica jdbc) file. and then I run lein uberjar: trying to pack that jar file into the standalone jar file, but after I run it, and uncompressed it, I can't find that vertica jdbc file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leiningen can create jar files, but the only place it picks them up from is your maven repository (under an `.m2` directory on your machine). Once your *special jar* is in maven you need to refer to it as a dependency in your `project.clj` file.

If your jar file was in clojars this would be quite easy - just put in a dependency - lein will fetch it into your maven repository. On the other hand if it was your own source code you would first need to `lein install` from the directory of that source code project.

However I'm guessing your file is just a jar file you have, which is not an artifact in clojars. In this case you can install it into your maven repository using this maven command (here assuming `my-deps.jar` is your file):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./my-deps.jar -DgroupId=my-deps -DartifactId=my-deps -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

You can then refer to it as a dependency in the *uberjar project*, and then `lein uberjar`.

Edit - if you don't want to use raw maven commands then consider using this leiningen library that abstracts them away for you: https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is to add to `project.clj:`

`:repositories {"local" "file:lib"}`

Create a lib directory in your project and add the jar there.

Add the lib reference in the `:dependencies` tag in `project.clj`.

This lib directory has the same structure as `.m2/repository` but is inside your project and local to your project