# lein Datomic :dev protocol gives `Unsupported protocol :dev`

Tags: datomic

This is the error I can't get rid of:

```
Unsupported protocol :dev  datomic.error/arg (error.clj:57)
```

I have been following various instructions found [here](https://my.datomic.com/account), [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/DEPLOY.md#authentication) and [here](https://github.com/metasoarous/datsys/wiki/Setting-up-Datomic-Pro).

In project.clj I have this in dependencies:

```
[com.datomic/datomic-pro "0.9.5350"]
```

This project worked fine when the above had `free` rather than `pro`.

Also this line in project.clj:

```
:repositories {"my.datomic.com" {:url "https://my.datomic.com/repo"
                                 :creds :gpg}}
```

In directory `~/.lein` I have an encrypted file called `credentials.clj.gpg` that was generated from a `credentials.clj` file that looks like this:

```
{#"my\.datomic\.com" {:username "chris@xxxxxxx.org"
                      :password "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}}
```

`gpg-agent` is running. But that doesn't seem to help either.

My main problem is that I don't know how this is all supposed to fit together. For instance how does lein know the public key to use to 
decrypt the `credentials.clj.gpg` file? Is lein using information from the page at "https://my.datomic.com/repo"?

From [here](https://github.com/metasoarous/datsys/wiki/Setting-up-Datomic-Pro) it does seem that there is a way to use `:dev` without having to have a gpg encrypted file.

**Summary**
I am looking to use a `:dev` Datomic database from a lein project, but the instructions I have found have not been clear enough for me to follow.

**More info**
To verify that you have installed `datomic-pro` onto your machine's `.m2` repo, here's (example of) where it will end up:

```
/home/your-unix-name/.m2/repository/com/datomic/datomic-pro/0.9.5385
```

Note that you should not run `maven-install` from the `bin` directory where it resides, but from the parent directory - that way it will be able to pick up the jar file which actually is in the parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of gpg to automate download of the Datomic distribution is one option for setting up Datomic. If you don't need to automate the process of fetching the Datomic bits, you can simply use the `bin/maven-install` script packaged with the Datomic distribution to install Datomic into your local maven repo. Simply download the distribution zip file from [my.datomic.com](https://my.datomic.com) and run `bin/maven-install` from the root of the unzipped distribution.

This process is also documented [here](http://docs.datomic.com/project-setup.html).

Best,
Marshall

Comment: I did do that earlier, and that's now where I run the transactor from and can use the repl. But it is a *local maven* rather than an *.m2 directory maven* solution, so not much help if you have multiple lein projects that will want to use datomic. I do understand that *.m2 directory maven* is not possible with datomic.

Comment: The `maven-install` script should install to your local .m2 maven repo, which can be used by any lein projects on the same system/user account.

Comment: My confusion was with the use of the word *local* - [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140802/lein-uberjar-doesnt-pack-the-jar-file-under-resource-into-the-final-jar/37142107#37142107) an example of the difference between *local* and *.m2*. So the *unusual* stuff you have to do in the lein project file is all about access to the Datomic jar going through a license, so that when the license expires there's no more access. No other purpose?

Comment: The gpg configuration is to allow lein (or maven) to download the Datomic peer library dependency directly from the private Datomic maven repo. Instead, you can download it yourself from the my.datomic.com website as a .zip file and use the `maven-install` script to install it into your maven repo.
The gpg credentials used to authorize the download (your download key) are entirely separate from the license key, which is emailed to you and placed in your transactor properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Having `gpg-agent` installed was the last thing I did - a step I initially
missed. I don't believe you have to run it manually. Anyway yesterday having it running didn't help, but re-launching IntelliJ today a dialog
popped up that asked for the passphrase and thus the application got 
past the `Unsupported protocol :dev` error message to a new one:

```
user=> (go)
ConnectException Connection refused  java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java:-2)
```

So I started the transactor and now the application is well and truly past
the hurdle of `:dev` being an unsupported protocol.